# Links Fail to Display in Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

For some reason the links in my navigation bar do not display in the browser at all, but my logo will!

I would like the logo to be on the left side of the screen and the links be positioned on the right side of the screen horizontally in the navigation bar.

Here is my HTML Code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lato-Regular";
  src: url("../fonts/Lato-Regular/Lato-Regular.ttf");
  src: url("../fonts/Lato-Regular/Lato-Regular.woff");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "PT-Sans";
  src: url("../fonts/PT-Sans/PTS55F.ttf");
  src: url("../fonts/PT-Sans/PTS55F.woff");
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  font-size: 0px;
  overflow-x: none;
}
body {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 1500px;
}
#navigation_bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
}
main {
  height: 1300px;
}
#container_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 865px;
  background-color: green;
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 435px;
  background-color: blue;
}
#copyright {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
img {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
a:link {
  font-family: "Lato-Regular", "PT-Sans", "Calibri Light", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 3.7em !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
}
a:hover {
  color: green;
}
li {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style: none;
  background: clear;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>My Website</title>
  <link href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="navigation_bar">
      <a href="images/logo.gif" class="logo" id="home">
        <img src="#" alt="Logo" title="Logo" />
      </a>
      <ul class="navbar_list">
        <li class="nav_list" id="about"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_list" id="films"><a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_list" id="other"><a href="#">Other</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--End of NAV-->
    <main id="container">
      <div id="container_wrapper">
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      </div>
    </main>
    <!--End of Main-->
    <footer id="copyright">
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!--End of WRAPPER-->
</body>

</html>
```

Question: How do I display a horizontal unordered list without bullet points in my navigation bar positioned to the right of the screen with my logo to the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `body {font-size:0px;}`, this makes all your text invisible.

`float: left;` on the logo (this way it doesn't push your navigation down)

Solution with above changes: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w2hmpvwm/1/)

Comment: thank you very much for your timely response. However, I have just one last question: when i fix my code with the above fixes a small white line appears near the top of my screen in the main browser window. How do I fix this, considering that I would like my navigation bar to stretch to the top of the screen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w2hmpvwm/2/ A number of changes were made, most notably your use of `nav` was incorrect. It should only be used to replace a `list` and not a `div` as seen here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp . This caused a lot of text complications.

Comment: thank you very much! however, howcome the list items are switched? it should be home, about, other, and for some reason its flipped.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w2hmpvwm/3/ Float the entire list to the right, float the list elements to the left